# Save value in uppercase when adding row to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three columns in the db table that looks as follow:
[image]

When I add a new row, it should store the value on column `fieldname` in uppercase. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you change the content to UPPER in the source instead of doing in ORM?

Comment: do you use code fisrt?

Comment: Bound datagrid? Windows forms?

Comment: More information please. Show us some code.

Comment: are you trying to find the EF equivalent of `UPPER(@Fieldname)` in SQL

Comment: If you're using Windows Forms Data Binding, then you can handle the `Binding.Parse` event on the DataGrid's binding. This gets called when you modify the value in a control that is bound to a datasource, and allows you to parse it however you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with *entity framework*, I assume you want to do it in your data layer or close to DB. There's a number of ways for doing this.

**You could override `SaveChanges()` in your context.** This will move the logic away from the model, but still ensure that the correct value is saved. Also, if you want it on several entities you can use an interface. When it's an `interface` you can do it for *several* of your entities without any duplicate code, as long as it's the same property. Otherwise you would need an attribute and reflection. Reusability is pretty high, but it adds some overhead to your `SaveChanges()`.

```
public class CustomerEntity()
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public MyCustomContext : DbContext
{    
    // Other stuff...

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<CustomerEntity>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                // Possibly check for null or if it's changed at all.
                entry.Entity.Name = entry.Entity.Name.ToUpper();
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And with an interface:

```
public interface INameIsAlwaysUpperCase
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

public MyCustomContext : DbContext
{    
    // Other stuff...

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<INameIsAlwaysUpperCase>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                // Possibly check for null or if it's changed at all.
                entry.Entity.Name = entry.Entity.Name.ToUpper();
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**You can add a custom validation.** This will throw exception if it's not saved correctly. That way you can move the responsibility to the consumer of the model. However, depending on your scenario, you might not want to throw an exception. This is my favourite since it forces the consumer to do it the *right way*. As per comments, *why throw when you can silently convert it*? Yes, it's a valid question. For me it's about forcing the consumer of the data layer to use it correctly, and not let the daya layer decide what to to with the data. I personally don't like it when the business layer asks the data layer to save one thing, and then the data layer saves another thing. If lower case isn't a valid option, then it shouldn't be  saved. I don't think it's much more different from using `[Required]`. But it's really about context and what works in your particular case.

```
public class CustomerEntity() : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Possibly check for null here as well...
        if (this.Name.ToUpper() != this.Name)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("You need to save as upper!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Use a property that manages this for you.** This may be the simplest solution, even if I like to keep my entities *"clean"*. It's absolutely the solution that will require least effort. However, the reusability is low, and what if you use your entitites all over the application and want the value to be lower case until it's actually saved? That's not possible. But, *again*, I think it comes down to your particular situation. If you want the value to be upper case *even before you save it*, this is probably the best solution!

```
public class CustomerEntity()
{
    string _name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value.ToUpper(); } // Check for null ?
    }
}
```

**Do it when saving.** This moves the logic to when you're saving your entity. This is probably the least preferable option, since the reusability is non-existing. What happens in `Update()`? However, the OP specifically states *"When I add a **new** row"*, so it may only be applicable when adding new entities. And in that case it could very well be the most prefered choice since it allows updates to have lower case. But it would have to depend on the use case.

```
public void AddCustomer(string name)
{
    var customer = new CustomerEntity
    {
        Name = name.ToUpper()
    };
    _context.Customers.Add(customer);
}
```

Comment: @zero_coding - Out of curiosity, what solution did you use?

Comment: I am using **Use a property that manages this for you***. I think right way to go, right?

Comment: @zero_coding - I would say it depends on your specific situation. I tend to use the _SaveChanges()-override_ and _custom validation_.

Comment: I do not know too, because I am new in EF6 world. So it is difficult choose the right way. So when the user read data from db, then they should pass in the where clause with UPPERCASE, in this case `SaveChanges()-override` would be better choice.

Comment: @smoksnes IMO, doing it in your model is the best solution. Because, generally it is model specific need and should be managed inside model. *Cons of using SaveChagnes:* If you have dozens of models and different properties must be uppercased, how would your SaveChanges look like? You have check if this Entity is Type of SomeType cast it and uppercase SomeProperty. *Cons of validation*: Why you would throw validation exception when you can silentyly convert it?

Comment: @AdilMammadov - I agree with you. I updated my answer with some comments about each solution, but I really think it depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

Just use properties. If your model is as below:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string FiledName { get; set; }   
}
```

Then, change it to:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private string fieldName;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string FiledName 
    { 
        get { return filedName; }
        set
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                fieldName = value.ToUpper();
            else
                fieldName = value;              
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: When using modern versions of C# the setter can be simplified to `fieldName = value?.ToUpper();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public string FiledName 
{ 
    get { return filedName; }
    set
    {
          filedName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) ? value.ToUpper() : value;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a ValueConverter on the Property could be an effective way to do this.

```cs
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Row> Rows { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        var converter = new ValueConverter<string, string>(
                v => v.ToUpper(), // writing
                v => v
        ); 

        // just one property
        modelBuilder.Entity<Row>()
                    .Property(x => x.Column) 
                    .HasConversion(converter);

        // all of the string properties
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.ClrType == typeof(string))
                {
                    builder.Entity(entityType.Name)
                           .Property(property.Name)
                           .HasConversion(converter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use a Custom Attribute :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class Standardized : Attribute
{}
```

Then decorate properties inside your model :

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Standardized]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Taken from @smoksnes accepted answer, inside your DbContext class, override `SaveChanges()`, `SaveChangesAsync()` (EF Core 5.x) and add a private method using reflection to obtain decorated properties and apply transformations, like this :

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    StandardizeBeforeSaving();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    StandardizeBeforeSaving();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

private void StandardizeBeforeSaving()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            var properties = entry.Entity
                .GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(Standardized)) && prop.PropertyType == typeof(string));

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var value = entry.CurrentValues[property.Name]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                entry.CurrentValues[property.Name] = value.Standardize();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just be aware that reflection could be slower than other techniques presented in accepted answer. But for most scenarios (ie. user updates or creates couple of entities with not that many properties) it should be fine.